# Is there a way to convert a groupby object into a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Using a data-set, I am trying to group the values on the basis of a key(order_id) using the groupby(). However, the return type being groupby object, I am not able to convert into a data frame which is the requirement.

I have tried using groupby to aggregate on the basis of a key. I also tried converting into a list.

```
import pandas as pd
table=pd.read_csv("chiporders.csv", sep='\t')
df_chiporders= pd.DataFrame(table)
type(df_chiporders)
type(df_chiporders['item_name'])
df_chiporders.item_name
df_grp=df_chiporders.groupby('order_id')['quantity'].apply(list)
print df_grp
```

Expected result : The result in a data Frame.

please refrain using `Count()`, `Sum()` because my answer should have the actual values in a dataframe

Comment: Use `df_grp=df_chiporders.groupby('order_id')['quantity'].apply(list).reset_index()`

Comment: OUTPUT :  print df_grp
order_id
1             [1, 1, 1, 1]
2                      [2]
3                   [1, 1]
4                   [1, 1]
5                   [1, 1]
....
1825    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
1826          [1, 1, 1, 1]
1827       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
1828             [1, 1, 1]
1829             [1, 1, 1]
1830                [1, 1]
1831             [1, 1, 1]
1832                [1, 1]
1833                [1, 1]
1834             [1, 1, 1]
Name: quantity, Length: 1834, dtype: object

print type(df_grp)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: Thanks, @jezrael .. It works. What is the L? in the data frame ! can we remove it ?

Comment: `L` ? Where is it?

Comment: Hi, @jezrael, it is not similar to the other question, i need to use the groupby(), this returns the groupby object, this object has to be converted to a data frame

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Using public dataset available here: [link]https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mathcoder3141/blog-data-files/master/Congress_White_House.csv

`import pandas as pd;
df = pd.read_csv('white_house_salary.csv');
df.columns;
df_grp = df.groupby('Position Title');
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df_grp);
new_df.to_csv("out.csv", sep = "\t");`

   This should be able to convert the groupby object to dataframe and then write to a csv file. Hope it helps.